# How to position anchors / nodes / anchornodes relative to one anchor with help of ARcore?

Tags: java, android, arcore

I'm creating inside building AR navigation in android studio. 
I'm looking for a way to "connect" the anchor with other anchors, or maybe anchor nodes / nodes. I'm not sure which one to use. Based on first anchor that i will force user to create I want to draw rest of a nodes that will be relative to the position of the first anchor. I've tried methods shown below but without success. Any ideas ?

```
private void getAnchors(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    double temp_x=0.0;
    double temp_y=0.0;
    double temp_z=0.0;
    Vector3 wektor3;

    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
          ObjectConversion vars = ds.getValue(ObjectConversion.class);
          temp_x = vars.getX();
          temp_y = vars.getY();
          temp_z = vars.getZ();

          wektor3 = new Vector3((float)temp_x,(float)temp_y,(float)temp_z);

          //Pose pose = new Pose(translation,rotation);
          Anchor anchor = download_hit_result.createAnchor();
          AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
          Node node = new Node();

          node.setParent(anchorNode);
          node.setWorldPosition(wektor3);
          node.setRenderable(andyRenderable);

          //anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
          //anchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
          //anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a mistake already. To anyone else who'll need to position objects based on diffrent objects. Simply, had to setParent of a anchornode to arFragment. I hope this helps anyone in the future:

```
private void getAnchors(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    double temp_x=0.0;
    double temp_y=0.0;
    double temp_z=0.0;
    long   temp_val=0;
    String temp_room="";
    float[] translation= new float[3];
    float[] rotation = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    Vector3 wektor3;
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        //TODO: create anchors with downloaded values when in the same position use hitpose.creatanchor with pose.

          ObjectConversion vars = ds.getValue(ObjectConversion.class);
          temp_x = vars.getX();
          temp_y = vars.getY();
          temp_z = vars.getZ();
          temp_room = vars.getRoom();
          temp_val=vars.getType();

          translation[0]=(float) temp_x;
          translation[1]=(float) temp_y;
          translation[2]=(float) temp_z;
          wektor3 = new Vector3((float)temp_x,(float)temp_y,(float)temp_z);
          Pose pose = new Pose(translation,rotation);

          Anchor anchorx = download_hit_result.getTrackable().createAnchor(pose);
          AnchorNode anchorNodex = new AnchorNode(anchorx);
          anchorNodex.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
          anchorNodex.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to download_hit_result  object ? can u provide any sample to generate downloadable hit results ?